# `ggplotly`, plotmath expressions and double labels in legend in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, plotmath

I have 2 issues using function `ggplotly` in R:

---

**Question 1** What are the ways to keep `R` *plotmath* expressions while converting `ggplot2` plots to `plotly` format using function `ggplotly`?

Now the expressions are converted to `[object Object]` as in this example below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars) +
    ggtitle(expression(bar(x) == sum(frac(x[i], n), i==1, n)))
```

[image]

```
ggplotly()
```

[image]

---

**Question 2**

How to get rid of **double** labels in the legend of `plotly` graph and make them look like in `ggplot2 graph`? I.e. how to get `6` in stead of `(6,6)`:

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = as.factor(cyl), fill = as.factor(cyl))
```

[image]

```
ggplotly()
```

[image]

Comment: for Q2, you could just use ggplot(aes(mpg, wt), data = mtcars) + geom_point(aes(colour = as.factor(cyl))), you don't need colour AND fill

Comment: I think you need to add titles with your HTML-fu rather than your R-plot.ly-fu.